# is there a way to add leading zeros to a time from a timediff

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Good Day,

I have this column--> timeT
1:32:9.123000

I want an out that shows --> timeT
01:32:09.123

Comment: how do you retrieve data from database?

Comment: Its the result from a timediff, actually I've reseaching for the leading left zeros but ican't do it right, I'm new to this. thank you.

Comment: I found this code here. $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table
                              SET table_total_time= CONCAT(
                              FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(table_Ltime,table_Rtime)) / 24), ':',
                              MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(table_Ltime,table_Rtime)), 24), ':',
                              MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(table_Ltime,table_Rtime)), ':',
                              SECOND(TIMEDIFF(table_Ltime,table_Rtime)), '.',
                              MICROSECOND(TIMEDIFF(table_Ltime,table_Rtime)))
                              ") or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: the result of the code is great, ex 0:1:1.111000, but I want it to have it formated like 00:01:01.111

Comment: @JuanDeLaCrus You can try `ROUND` function on `MICROSECOND` function to reduce the digits in microsecond.

Comment: also how about the leading zero's on hurs min and seconds. thanks

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? Plus what is the data type of the table_total_time column?

Comment: Im using phpmyadmin and my datatype is char(20). thank you

Comment: @JuanDeLaCrus Can you give sample value of table_Ltime column?

Comment: @JuanDeLaCrus Use LPAD() function like LPAD(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(table_Ltime,table_Rtime)), 2, 0). Since it will add leading 0 in case minute is in single digit. If it works then use it in other parameters as well like Hours , seconds.